# get session variable in runtime

Tags: asp.net, session, variables

There are more web applications (asp.net 4) in own virtual directory of IIS server (under win2003).
And appertain to all own schema and account in oracle 11g database.
After login all users have some session variables (like username,shema name ...etc). I want to get these information for user management in runtime. How can I ask it from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this?

To retrieve:

```
string username = Session["Username"];
```

To put things on Session:

```
Session["Username"]="SomeValue";
```

Comment: will this work when at the given moment many users are entered into more given web apllications ? I have to know  the all users wich are entered into web applications at the same time.

Comment: @user1651977 I see. No, this won't. Your question wasn't clear. You need to keep track of this on a different way, perhaps handling the `Session_Start` event in `Global.asax` by inserting a record in database table or something every time a new session is started. Google a bit and you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: @user1651977 here's a useful link for you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1689960.aspx/1

Comment: sorry! to make it clear! i think that all the necessary information about all the users (for example session variables...)  who entered into some web applicatins in IIS, are stored in accassible data structure in iis, and when the user leave the application the data will be removed from the structure. that is my point at a given moment structure contains all the data of all the connected users and nothing else.that is exactly the information that i would like to get out of the structure withouth using any extra database